# calling function nested within ng-repeat not returning correct value to $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to count the number of trivia questions a user has answered. For each questio (statement), where the value is greater than 0 -- that indicates the question is answered. I can see these correct values in the console.log, but I cannot get the value to show in $scope or displayed on the frontend: It displays a number, but the number does not match the results of the console.log:

html / haml :

```
categories(ng-repeat='category in service.categories' ng-class="{'first':$first}" )
.row(ng-click='showQuestions = !showQuestions' ng-class="{'ballotSelected' : showQuestions}")
  .label
    .chevron(ng-class="showQuestions ? 'fa fa-chevron-down ballotSelected' : 'fa fa-chevron-right'")
    .name.text-uppercase
      {{category.name}} {{category.statements.length}}
    .questionCount(ng-init='getStatementCount(category)')
      {{statementCounts}}
.showRow(ng-show='showQuestions')
```

controller:

```
    $scope.getStatementCount = function(category) {
  var i, questionCount;
  console.log(category);
  i = 0;
  questionCount = 0;
  while (i < category.statements.length) {
    if (category.statements[i].value > 0) {
      questionCount += 1;
    }
    i++;
  }
  console.log(questionCount, 'COUNT');
  return $scope.statementCounts = questionCount;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eevery time you call `getStatementsCount()`, you overwrite a *unique* scope variable `statementCounts`, that is displayed for all the categories.

That can't be right.

So,

- either you store the result in the category itself, and display the category's result in each category. You should do that without using ng-init, in the controller, as soon as the categories are loaded/provided.
- or you don't assign any variable with the result, and display the result directly in the page:

.

```
$scope.getStatementCount = function(category) {
    ...
    return questionCount;
}
```

and

```
.questionCount
  {{ getStatementCounts(category) }}
```

Comment: Awesome. Makes perfect sense.